# Need help to understand deserialization with ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist, casting, deserialization

I want write an ArrayList to a file and then read it back again. The list is going to hold Integer objects. Serialization seems to be working fine but I'm having trouble deserilaizing. More specifically I can'get the casting right.

The serialization:

```
ObjectOutputStream ou =
    new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("load.dat")));

ArrayList<Integer> ouList = new ArrayList<>();
ou.writeObject(ouList);
ou.close();
```

The derserilazation:

```
ObjectInputStream in =
    new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStrean("load.dat"));
ArrayList<Integer> inList = (ArrayList<Integer>)(in.readObject();
in.close();
```

When I compile I get unchecked and unsafe warning. I recompiled with Xclint:unchecked and got the following message:

```
warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    ArrayList<Integer> inList = (ArrayList<Integer>)(in.readObject());
                                                    ^
  required: ArrayList<Integer>
  found:    Object
```

I find this somewhat confusing: Isn't the casting supposed to convert the object to arraylist? Why does it require ArrayList when that's what I'm casting it to? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What happens when you remove the parentheses around in.readObject(). Try this     ArrayList<Integer> inList = (ArrayList<Integer> )in.readObject();

Comment: Casting generics from Object result in unchecked cast, removing generics solve the unchecked warning, but if you need rawtype ignore the warning a use try/catch as suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It tells your that the compiler is unable to guarantee you that the cast would be successful in runtime - it may produce `ClassCastException`.

Usually you are able to check type previously with `instanceof` to prevent this warning, e.g.:

```
if (x instanceof ArrayList) {
    ArrayList y = (ArrayList) x; // No warning here 
}
```

Unfortunately `instanceof` can't check generic parameters at run-time, so you won't be able to perform this operation safely. All you can do is suppress the warning.

However if you really want to be assured of the type of the collection, then you can alter your code in the next way:

```
public class ArrayListOfIntegers extends ArrayList<Integer> {}

...

// writing:
ArrayListOfIntegers ouList = new ArrayListOfIntegers();
...
// reading:
ArrayListOfIntegers inList;
Object readData = in.readObject();
if (readData instanceof ArrayListOfIntegers) {
    inList = (ArrayListOfIntegers) readData;
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("...");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are getting unchecked/unsafe warnings I would suggest putting those in try/catch blocks.

Here is a relatively straightforward tutorial doing exactly what you are trying to do: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/how-to-serialize-arraylist-in-java/

Comment: This tutorial also throws the same warnings, is it a common thing to just leave unsafe operations like this hanging as long as the exceptions will be caught?